# How to load matlab file in colab?

Tags: python, matlab, google-colaboratory

I want to load a **MATLAB** file into **COLAB** using

```
scipy.io.loadmat('../Data/burgers_shock.mat')
```

I don't know how to set the path for `.mat` file and where to keep the `.mat` file.

Comment: May be your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54628516/read-mat-file-from-github-in-google-colab

Answer (score 3):

1. upload your .mat file on your drive.
2. add these lines at the top of your code 
   from google.colab import drive
   drive.mount('/content/drive')
3. then just load using the following path 
   S=scipy.io.loadmat('/content/drive/My Drive/burgers_shock.mat');